# Android generic layout for all screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, scale

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.main.turkkusu.radyo.MessageFragment"
             android:id="@+id/scream_frame">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <EditText

                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:maxLength="150"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/message_scream_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                android:hint="Bir şeyler söyleyin..."
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:text="Gönder"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/message_scream_button"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/message_scream_text"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_scream_text"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/scream_progressbar" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:id="@+id/pool_layout">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scream_scroll"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/message_pool_view"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Above is my layout code and the appareances for the different screen densities. Even tought I use `DP` scale for the measurement, I get different results for different phones. Do I really have to make all different kinds of layouts for different densities?

Comment: It is better, not hard code width but use relative to screen `match_parent` with paddings or margins

Comment: Use also have useless `FrameLayout` which you can simply remove